# Throw no default value error even if we give value

Tags: mariadb

A user of one of my product is using `MySQL 10.7.3-MariaDB`.

This is the table creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS negativity_accounts
(
    id CHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    reports VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
);
```

When my product run :

```sql
REPLACE INTO table (id, reports) VALUES ('my-id', '');
```

It throw error: "Field 'reports' doesn't have a default value".

This request works with all mysql versions that I tested for multiple years, so what's the new behavior and how can I fix it without breaking all others DB ?

Comment: Is there a Trigger on `negativity_accounts`?

Comment: @RickJames No, there is no trigger, no view, no specific constraint

Comment: It is my understanding that 
    reports VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
defines a column named reports that does not allow NULL - so put something in it, maybe UNK until someone looks up and knows they need a value to be successful.

Comment: @WilsonHauck empty is not null, so I put empty at begin, and it works since long time with all mysql versions

Comment: Your test cse (except for the table name) works fine on MySQL 8.0.  I would expect it to be fine on 10.7, too.  Is it `ENGINE=InnoDB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the [`EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#empty_string_is_null) SQLMode variable set to true.

Comment: Oracle compatibility mode?